# LINQ - take x objects from database for each object property value

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-2.0

I have an entity:

```
public class Component
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ProductType Type { get; set; }
}
```

ProductType

```
public enum ProductType
{
    Harddrive = 1,
    GraphicCard,
    ComputerCase,
}
```

I'm trying to get list of **Product** that contains 15 random items (5 per ProductType) in single LINQ.

**ComputerCase, GraphicCard and Harddrive inherts from same base class**

For now I have something like that:

```
        var response = db.Components
            .Select(x => new Product
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
                Type = x.Type,
            }).ToList();
```

but I have no idea how could I achive what I need. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: use `Take(5)` to select 5 items from each `ProductType`

Comment: How can I specify to take 5 items from each `ProductType` ?
`var response = db.Components
            .Select(x => new Product
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
                Type = x.Type,
            }).Take(5).ToList();` won't work

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible with single db query in EF Core yet. Eventually with 3 queries - one for each  ProductType.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer @IvanStoev

Answer (score 0):

Make groups of `Components` with the same `ProductType`. From the resulting collection of groups take the first `Component` in the group. From that result take the first 5, items.

```
var result = myComponents.                    // take the collection of Components
    .GroupBy(component => component.Type)     // group this into groups of components with same Type
    .Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault())  // from every group take the first element
    .Take(5)                                  // take only the first five
```

Of course, if you really want a proper random, you'll have to fetch all `Component` groups to local memory and use `RND` to extract random groups and random element from each selected group